# What colour would you make the inside of a chili bin?

Tags: thermodynamics

[image]

Hi there,

If you were making a cooler (a thing you put your iced drinks and ice blocks in to keep them cool), what colour would you make the inside of it? Black would absorb more heat, while white would reflect heat. Which colour would be the best?

Comment: There's a reason that every commercial cooler on the planet is white :-) See [this other post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/159856/why-is-black-the-best-emitter).

Comment: I would say that if the environment is always warmer than the inner doesn't count. The only important thing is to prevent heat coming from outside. But all bags and box I remember are white or metallic reflective even inside, and the same is true for freezers and laboratory ice-makers.

Answer (score 1):

The color of the inner surface won't matter much though the color of the outer surface will. The objective is to make an environment as cool as possible to cool down the drinks. White reflects heat and hence should be chosen as the color of both the outer (obviously) and inner surface as if the inner surface is colored black, it'll absorb the heat radiating from the hot drinks. But this surface is also in contact with the bottles and hence has the potential to heat them again. So the only option left is to color the surface white as it'll reflect the heat from the bottles. Hope this helps you. Feel free to have any queries

Comment: Thanks so much. Would silver be better than white for the inside?